# Autohotkey - Hidden File Hotkey

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I am trying to get a hotkey to toggle hidden files. I got this one but when I hit <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> it does nothing. I am running Windows 7 64-Bit.

```
;Show hidden folders and files in Windows XP
#h::
RegRead, ShowHidden_Status, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced, Hidden
f ShowHidden_Status = 2 
RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced, Hidden, 1
Else
RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced, Hidden, 2
WinGetClass, CabinetWClass
PostMessage, 0x111, 28931,,, A
Return
```

Answer (score 2):

I learned recently from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8110982/104370) that when changing registry keys for Windows Explorer settings, the results only show when Explorer restarts.

This means that you either need to log out and back in, or kill the Explorer process, which would then automatically restart itself. Any open Explorer windows would disappear, though.

Although I'm not able to test it at the moment this thread [Kill explorer from script](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic58367.html) looks like it shows how to do it:

```
process, close, explorer.exe
```